# wrong use of logical operators in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell. I tried compiling some examples, but I don't know what the compiler is trying to tell me.
this is my code:

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

max' :: int->int->int
max' n m 
        | (n <= m) = m
        | otherwise = n

maximum' :: [int]->int
maximum' [a]=a
maximum' (x:xs) = max' x (maximum' xs)

sort' :: [int]->[int]
sort' [] =[]
sort' (x:xs) = sort'[y|y<-(x:xs),y < maximum'(x:xs)]++[y'|y'<-(x:xs),y' == maximum'(x:xs)]
```

and this is the output of the compiler:

```
Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Failed, modules loaded: none.

test.hs:6:22:
    No instance for (Ord int) arising from a use of ‘<=’
    Possible fix:
      add (Ord int) to the context of
        the type signature for max' :: int -> int -> int
    In the expression: (n <= m)
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                   an equation for ‘max'’:
      (n <= m)
    In an equation for ‘max'’:
        max' n m
          | (n <= m) = m
          | otherwise = n

test.hs:15:36:
    No instance for (Ord int) arising from a use of ‘<’
    Possible fix:
      add (Ord int) to the context of
        the type signature for sort' :: [int] -> [int]
    In the expression: y < maximum' (x : xs)
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: y < maximum' (x : xs)
    In the first argument of ‘sort'’, namely
      ‘[y | y <- (x : xs), y < maximum' (x : xs)]’

test.hs:15:73:
    No instance for (Eq int) arising from a use of ‘==’
    Possible fix:
      add (Eq int) to the context of
        the type signature for sort' :: [int] -> [int]
    In the expression: y' == maximum' (x : xs)
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: y' == maximum' (x : xs)
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
      ‘[y' | y' <- (x : xs), y' == maximum' (x : xs)]’
```

the compiler is pointing to all the logical operators in my code

Comment: `Int` is the primitive integer type in haskell. `int` is treated as a type variable.

Comment: thanks @zakyggaps. that worked